# How to add DropDown in Android application

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I want to add drop down list in android application.
Can anybody tell me, how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Android does not have any '*Drop Down*' Option. You should use the '*Spinner*' instead of.

Here is the implementation of Spinner:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont have drop down option in android. you can use spinner instead. use this link for spinner,it absolutely work well in eclipse.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html